# Reshape django queryset to display in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am learning Django and trying to build a simple student grade publishing system. I have set up my model classes as follow:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rollNum=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    faculty=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tutorial(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Grade(models.Model):
    grade=models.CharField(max_length=2)
    student=models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tutorial=models.ForeignKey(Tutorial,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.name+ '|' + self.tutorial.name+ '|' +self.grade  
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('student','tutorial')
```

`Grade.objects.filter().values_list('student__name','tutorial__name','grade')` is returning QuerySet in following form:

```
Student1 Tutorial1 A
Student2 Tutorial1 A+
Student1 Tutorial2 B
Student1 Tutorial3 A
```

How can I reshape the result into the following form?

```
Student Tutorial1 Tutorial2 Tutorial 3
Student1     A       B         A
Student2     A+      X         X
```

I want to render this in django template.

Edit: My view

```
def results(request):
    grades=Grade.objects.filter().values_list('student__name','tutorial__name','grade')
    return render(request,'results/index.html',{"a":grades})
```

Earlier, I tried to simplify the data sent to the template  in following form:

```
{'Student1': {'Tutorial1': 'A', 'Tutorial1': 'A'}, 'Student2': {'Tutorial2': 'A'}, 'Student3': {'Tutorial1': 'A', 'Tutorial1': 'A'}}
```

using following code in views.py

```
def results(request):
    grades=Grade.objects.filter().values_list('student__name','tutorial__name','grade')
    dic1=defaultdict(list)
    dic2=defaultdict(list)
    for s,t,g in grades:
        if t not in dic1:
            dic1[t]=g
        dic2[s]=dict(dic1)
    return render(request,'results/index.html',{"a":dict(dic2)})
```

Unfortunately I couldn't come up with a logic to use the data returned into the template

Comment: Can you please show your views?

Comment: If you use django's built-in generic views, this would be easier to achieve: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/. Then you can overwrite the `get_context_data` function if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like(after you have created the dictionary) in your templates-

```
{% for st in a.keys %}
// st is the student name
{{ st }}
{% for tut in a[st].keys %}
// tut is tutorial name and a[st][tut] is the grade
{{ tut }}
{{ a[st][tut] }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Place them appropriately in table.